# Javascript auto click not working on hi5/tagged website

Tags: javascript, jquery

On tagged.com i'm trying to buy pet automatically with javascript. On every page my codes working very good. But on m.tagged.com/pets/ownedpets.html url my codes does not react at all. I have try many variaton codes. But result is same. My codes cant click. Wonder bcz a element dont have link my codes not work? Excuse me for my bad english.

I tried this code for auto click and buy pets.

setInterval(function() {
  $("a.id-buy-again.green.ui-btn.ui-shadow.ui-btn-corner-all.ui-mini.ui-btn-hover-c.ui-btn-up-c").click();
}, 2000);

```
<a data-role="button" data-mini="true" class="id-buy-again green ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-mini ui-btn-hover-c ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Buy Again</span></span></a>
```

Comment: Anyone can help pls ?

Comment: use `.trigger('click');` in  setinterval

Comment: i tried this code and stil not work :(

Comment: add event `.on('click')` to button on page load first, `.trigger('click')` will work if your element have event click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try setInterval to setTimeout and remove unnecessary classes

```
setTimeout(function() { $(".id-buy-again").click(); }, 2000);
```

Comment: Cevabın için teşekkür ederim Umut. Her türlüsünü denedim herhangi birsonuç çıkmadı maalesef :( div içinde gömülü olan span elementlerini tek tek seçtim olmadı, a içindekini seçtim olmadı. Çok uzun süredir denememerağmen herhangi bir sonuç alamadım. Bir ara vazgeçtikten sonra yine merak sardı neden olmuyor diye. Sitede aratınca aynı sorundan muzdarip biri daha vardı. Yine onda da a elementindeherhangi bir link çıkışı yoktu bendeki gibi.